# Splitting strings based on multiple rules and values

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to construct a SQL INSERT statement from some data in an Excel spreadsheet.  Here is some sample data:

```
ORIGINAL       |     DESIRED OUTPUT
ND                   0, null
0.23                 0.23, null
0.45 J               0.45, 1
0.99 B               0.99, 2
```

So the rules would be:

- If there is a ND the ND should be converted to a 0 and the next field will be a null
- If there is just a number we just add that number as is plus a null field
- If there is a 'J' after the number the output fields should be the number and then a '1'
- If there is a 'B' after the number the output fields should be the number and then a '2'

I can create individual rules without too much trouble, but I can't seem to string them together.  For example:

```
=IF(A1="ND","0, null",A1)
```

The above will take care of the first instance of 'ND', but not sure how to add in the other rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(A1="ND","0, null",IF(RIGHT(A1)="J",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&", 1",IF(RIGHT(A1)="B",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&", "&2,A1&", null")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested IF formulas:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1&", null",IF(A1="ND","0, null",IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="J",TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))&", 1",IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="B",TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))&", 2","UNKNOWN"))))
```

An IF statement is comprised of 3 sections:

**=IF(***condition_test***,***true_part***,***false_part***)**

In the *false_part* you can start another =IF() formula - lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score -2):

You can nest if statements:

=IF(A1="ND","0, null", if(right(a1,1)="J", a1 & "1", if(right(a1,1)="B", a1 & "2", A1)))

And so on.